# jQuery $.inArray() returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

if you have a array like `('a', 'b')` and check `$.inArray('a', thearray);` you get the index, which is 0, and could be false. So you need to check the result further and it's annoying...

Is there a quick method trough which I can get only true/false, and not the indexes?

basically I have a string in a html5 data attribute: `data-options="a,b,c"` and 3 a, b, c variables in javascript that must take true/false values based on what's inside data-options...

Comment: *"Description: Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found)."* - from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/04/did-you-know-episode-ii.html contains a nice way to achieve that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that by invoking the `binary NOT` operator.

```
if( ~$.inArray('a', thearray) ) {
}
```

Explained in detail here: [typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/04/did-you-know-episode-ii.html](http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/04/did-you-know-episode-ii.html)

Comment: What you lose in speed you more than make up for in sheer, unadulterated manliness.

Comment: to uglify + clearify this, you could also use `!!~$.inArray('a', thearray)`

Comment: @Alex: `!!` forces the result to be a boolean value. So `-4` or `11` for instance would get turned into `true`, whereas `0` for instance gets turned into `false`. Anyway, I don't recommend it here, since it looks pretty alien :-)

Comment: nah, I'm using it like `a = !!~$.inArray('a', thearray);` :D thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Test against `-1`:

```
$.inArray('a', arr) !== -1
```

The above expression will return true/false.

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely
>   equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0
>   !== false), if we're checking for the
>   presence of value within array, we
>   need to check if it's not equal to (or
>   greater than) -1.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 4):

Yep, compare to -1.

```
if ($.inArray('a', thearray) === -1) {
    // not found
}
```

You could wrap that into another function if it really bugs you:

```
function myInArray(needle, haystack) {
    return $.inArray(needle, haystack) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: I like wrapping logic in a reusable component. Kudos @nickf